# What's the practice for Github cascading merge?

Tags: git, github

Is there any option or practice in github which provides auto PR cascading like bitbucket (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/automatic-branch-merging-776639993.html)?

Basically if I merge a PR to a release-candidate branch, it will also merge the changes to master as well.

Answer (score 5):

Github doesn't have this capability at present and this feature is not mentioned in [Collaborating with issues and pull requests](https://help.github.com/categories/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/) help section. You can try to implement it with server-side hooks but it's not provided by Github as a repository configuration option.

Perhaps that's because Github suggests [GitHub-flow](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flow/) which unlike Git-flow doesn't use a separate release candidate branch.