# Github - merging commits pull requests to several branches

Tags: github, git-merge, pull-request

We added a flow of mandatory pull requests when pushing code to our 3 main branches - dev, releaseCandidtae and production.

the flow is:
dev -> feature-branch -> pull request and merge back to dev
                                          merge\cherry pick to releaseCandiadte branch
                                          merge\cherry pick to production branch
Sometimes the feature branch is a fix and go out from production branch and cherry picked back to dev.

I understand that the code base might be different but is there a way to merge a commit to a all branches with one pull request?
Maybe there a better way to build the branches hierarchy for that process? 
currently all went out from master branch.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow you describe sounds a bit unusual to me and I'm not sure in what cases you plan to merge to all branches. The more common flow, [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), allows the concept of a "cascading merge," which is supported by some services.

Bitbucket, for example, supports automatic cascade merges, as you can read about here.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/automatic-branch-merging-776639993.html

As far as I know, GitHub does not support it. Most likely because it's not a useful feature for [GitHub-flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

This question and answer is related. [What's the practice for Github cascading merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021689/whats-the-practice-for-github-cascading-merge)

Comment: Thanks Peter, you are right it is a flow I took from my previous work place which doesn't fit pull requests and CI\CD. we will adapt and change :)